# that no matter what the inputs are Motor1 always moves

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

```
int motor_forward1 = 7;
int motor_reverse1 = 6;
int motor_forward2 = 5;
int motor_reverse2 = 4;
int motor_forward3 = 3;
int motor_reverse3 = 2;
int sensor1 = A0;
int sensor2 = A1;

 void setup() 
{

   pinMode(motor_forward1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse1, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_forward2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse2, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_forward3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(motor_reverse3, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(sensor1, INPUT);
   pinMode(sensor2, INPUT);
 }

 void loop()
 {
   if (digitalRead(A0) == HIGH)
   {
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,1);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward1,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse1,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   else if (digitalRead(A1) == HIGH)
   {
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,1); 
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward2,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse2,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   else
   {
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,1); 
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,0);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,1);
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(motor_forward3,0);
     digitalWrite(motor_reverse3,0);
     delay(1000);
   }
   delay(5000);
 }
```

Schematic [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fz92a.png).

Comment: Could you add a little bit more than an un-formatted dump of code? Also circuit diagrams, possibly images... won't get closed then

Comment: @RSM before this I don't have any input and not using If else statement. My motor can rotate forward and reverse. after using if else statement my circuit not function correctly. How want to put image here?

Comment: An external link to the schematic is fine for now. I don't know why you're using a 5V regulator for each of the inputs - it seems a strange way of doing things. Proteus has some odd quirks, so pull each input to ground with a 10k resistor (between the switch and the Arduino) and see if that helps.

Comment: @RSM my push button in schematic circuit act as sensor. this software didn't have suitable sensor.

Comment: @CharlieHanson my sensor 5v at the input. my project using 2 sensor.

Comment: Be sure you if/else nestings are as you intend.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I think switch/case and if/else most suitable in my project. I more understand using If/case. you have any idea about my project?

Comment: OK, that makes sense now, thank you. You say it doesn't function correctly - what *does* it do? It's very clear from the code what you want to happen, but we need to know what you're seeing. Update the question to say, for example, that no matter what the inputs are Motor2 always moves, or whatever it actually is.

Comment: @CharlieHanson my problem is when run the simulation and push the either button 1 or 2 only the motor1 always move. what I want in this project when push button 1 motor1 run forward and reverse and push button 2 the motor2 also run forward and reverse. the motor stop when the both button not push.

Comment: Looks like you use digitalRead to read analog pins A0, A1. Try changing to analogRead or using digital pins.

Comment: @tamberg I already change but it's didn't work. motor3 only run. I don't know what problem in my coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't wrong, it's far too simple to be at fault.

The error is from within Proteus. Those 'pushbutton' switches (and the other switch simulations) are not quite as straightforward as one would like. They have an OFF resistance, usually 100 Megaohms, but that's enough to trick the simulation into not behaving like it should do. You MUST pull the inputs to ground with a resistor - any sensible value will do as it's only required for the *simulation*. As they are, they're in some odd floating/magic/unknown state; common sense does not apply here!

An alternative is to swap the pushbutton for a SPDT switch; connect the common to the Arduino and the other contacts to the 7805 output and ground. You won't need the resistor in this case.

Comment: OK. Which code I need to use? mine code or need to replace "pinMode(sensor1, INPUT); pinMode(sensor2, INPUT);" to "pinMode(sensor1, INPUT_PULLUP); pinMode(sensor2, INPUT_PULLUP);"

Comment: I'd sick with the original code. Using `INPUT_PULLUP` will work but that places restrictions on the value of your external pulldown resistors. Nothing a bit of maths and datasheet-reading won't solve, but it's just extra work.